# Max depth exceeded message while building a docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I had made few changes in a Dockerfile and now when I am trying to build it I am getting the following error "**max depth exceeded**". I guess that the number of layers is being quite high:

> docker history [REPO/IMAGE] | wc -l
>
> 175

How would you suggest to fix it? This Dockerfile should be constantly be updated.

Comment: If the number of layers is really that high, then the first step is refactor to reduce them, by combining e.g. `apt-get update && apt-get install -y xxx && apt-get install -y zzz`

Comment: Hi Siha, thanks for your reply. I do agree that the dockerfile commands should be combined. But, do you know if it's possible to merge the layers once the container is already with 175 layers?

Comment: https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-flatten-an-image-with-127-parents/1600